# Binding Directive attribute to Controller not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am currently stuck in a situation and the scenario is I want to bind the directive to my HTML but nothing works I want to bind directive scope with HTML
this is what I am doing:

this is my directive what I want is to bind the attribute **file** to  my HTML so I can get the name of **file** and **modified date**

```
.directive("fileinput", [function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                file: "=",
                filepreview: "="
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
                element.bind("change", function(changeEvent) {
                    scope.file = changeEvent.target.files[0];
                    scope.filepreview='';

                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function(loadEvent) {
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            console.log(scope.file)//printing file value but not reflect in html

                            scope.filepreview = loadEvent.target.result;
                            var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
                            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 130);
                            var img = new Image();
                            img.src = scope.filepreview ;
                            img.onload = function() {
                                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

                            }


                        });
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(scope.fileinput);
                });
            }
        }
    }])
```

**index.html**

```
<div class='form-group required'>
   <label>{{file.LastModified}}</label>
     <input type="file"  fileinput="file" filepreview="filepreview"/>


  </div>
```

Nothing happens when I upload file  but in directive, I am getting file 
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

your directive scope has "file" object but you are using "fileInput" to get the file , Can you try below code

```
<input type="file" fileinput file="file" filepreview="filepreview"/>
```